# Hugo template to HTML, CSS, JS

Tags: html, r-markdown, hugo, hugo-theme, hugo-content-organization

Hey i was just wondering if it possible to convert a Hugo site to vanilla HTML, CSS and JS? If there is, can someone tell me how and if there are any online site to generate them automatically.

Thanks in advance.

```
hugo serve
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is actually very simple. Run the command `hugo` and then look at the generated 'public' folder. This contains your website in vanilla HTML, CSS and JS.